# SignalR + Knockout + EntityFramework (classic aspx webforms, not mvc) how to date mask

Tags: jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

Currently, my page.html is as follows, it's mostly working but i have some oddities,  my dates show like this:

```
2013-05-24T13:09:40.927 2013-05-24T13:09:40.927 10>  
 •2013-05-24T13:11:32.823 2013-05-24T13:11:32.823 100>  
 •2013-05-24T13:12:22.653 2013-05-24T13:12:22.653 10>  
 •2012-12-12T00:00:00 2012-12-12T00:00:00 10>
```

and it would be nice to date parse them, but not sure how to do this, also I would like the 2 input fields:

```
<input type="date" class="ui-corner-all" data-bind="value: newPeriodFrom" />
               <input type="date" class="ui-corner-all" data-bind="value: newPeriodTo" />
```

to be  date pickers  or even better masked date fields, how is this possible?

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
        <body>`enter code here`
        <script src="Core/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
         <script src="Core/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js"></script>
          <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
           <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>   
            <script src="/Core/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="GUI/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="GUI/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <script src="Core/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"></script>
            <!-- when this page is loaded into the dom, the inner html of this div will be re-written to `be the session id, feels hacky but works -->
            <div id="sessionIdDiv">174f869f-cf27-4dd4-a031-d518fa5eb9cc</div>
    <!-- ReSharper disable StatementIsNotTerminated -->
            <script>
                $(function () {

                    //call this func to open a connection before calling  hub methods ie window.hubReady.done(function....



                   // $(function () {
                   //     window.hubReady = $.connection.periodTransactionComs.start();
                  ////  });

                    //returns the context session ID 
                    function sessionId() {                   
                        var licenceGuid = $('#sessionIdDiv').text();
                        return licenceGuid;
                    }

                    //poll the server for updates, gives us "realtime", 
                    //ie any updates directly to SQL or anywhere else will be 
                    //dragged in, helps prevent dirty data  my old cache engine caused.
             ///      $(function() {
               //     window.setInterval(function() {
             //           this.hub = $.connection.periodTransactionComs;
                  //      this.hub.server.getAll(sessionId());
    //
               //     }, 1000);



                    //the main KO view model 
                    function periodViewModel(periodId, validFrom, validTo, number, ownerViewModel) {
                        this.pId = periodId;
                        this.validFrom = ko.observable(validFrom);
                        this.validTo = ko.observable(validTo);
                        this.number = ko.observable(number);
                        this.remove = function () { ownerViewModel.removePeriod(this.pId) }
                        this.notification = function (b) { notify = b }


                        this.validFrom.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                            ownerViewModel.updatePeriod(ko.toJS(self));
                        });

                        this.validTo.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                            ownerViewModel.updatePeriod(ko.toJS(self));
                        });

                        this.number.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                            ownerViewModel.updatePeriod(ko.toJS(self));
                        });


                    }


                    //Task List View Model
                    function periodListViewModel() {
                        //Handlers for our Hub callbacks

                        this.hub = $.connection.periodTransactionComs;
                        this.periods = ko.observableArray([]);
                        this.newPeriodFrom = ko.observable();
                        this.newPeriodTo = ko.observable();
                        this.newPeriodNumber = ko.observable();
                       var periods = this.periods;
                        var self = this;
                        var notify = true;
                      this.newPeriodFrom();
                      this.newPeriodTo();
                      this.newPeriodNumber("1");

                        //Initializes the view model
                        this.init = function () {

                            this.hub.server.getAll(sessionId());

                        }

                        //map the JSON to a KO model
                     this.hub.client.periodAll = function (allPeriods) {
                         var mappedPeriods = $.map(allPeriods, function (item) {
                             alert("Mapping id:" + item.Id + " number " + item.number + " Number:" + item.Number + " From: " + item.ValidFrom + " to: " + item.ValidTo);
                                return new periodViewModel(item.Id, item.ValidFrom, item.ValidTo,
                                         item.Number, self)
                            });
                         periods(mappedPeriods);
                     }



                        //server dynamicly calls this method when a row is updated in this context
                        //only returns to caller connected.
                        this.hub.client.periodUpdated = function (t) {
                            var period = ko.utils.arrayFilter(periods(),
                                         function (value)
                                         { return value.pId == t.Id; })[0];
                            notify = false;
                            period.validFrom(t.ValidFrom);
                            period.validTo(t.ValidTo);
                            period.number(t.Number);
                            alert("periodupdated:  " + t.ValidFrom + " " + t.validTo + "  " + t.Number);
                            notify = true;
                        };

                        //all serverside errors will dynamicly calll this to report errors.
                        this.hub.client.reportError = function (error) {
                            $("#error").text(error);
                            $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function () {
                                $("#error").fadeOut(3000);
                                alert(error);
                            });
                        }
                        //dynamicly called add method updates clientside viewmodel.
                        this.hub.client.periodAdded = function (t) {

                            periods.push(new periodViewModel(t.Id, t.ValidFrom, t.ValidTo, t.Number, self));
                            alert("Period Added Id:" + t.Id + " number " + t.number + " Number:" + t.Number + " From: " + t.ValidFrom + " to: " + t.ValidTo);
                        };
                        //dynamicly called add method updates clientside viewmodel.
                        this.hub.client.periodRemoved = function (periodId) {
                            var period = ko.utils.arrayFilter(periods(), function (value) { return value.pId == periodId; })[0];
                            periods.remove(period);
                        };
                        //View Model 'Commands'

                        //To create a task
                        this.addPeriod = function () {
                            var t = { "validFrom": this.newPeriodFrom(), "validTo": this.newPeriodTo(), "number": this.newPeriodNumber() };
                            alert("values of add  " + this.newPeriodFrom() + this.newPeriodTo() + this.newPeriodNumber());
                            this.hub.server.add(t,sessionId()).done(function () {
                                alert('added')
                            }).fail(function (e) {
                                alert(e);
                            });
                            this.newPeriodFrom("");
                          this.newPeriodTo("");
                           this.newPeriodNumber("0");
                        }

                        //To remove a task client side only
                        this.removePeriod = function (periodId) {
                            this.hub.server.remove(periodId);
                        }

                        //To update this task client side only
                        this.updatePeriod = function (period) {
                            if (notify)
                                alert('notify');
                                this.hub.server.update(period);
                        }


                    }

                    var vm = new periodListViewModel();
                    ko.applyBindings(vm);
                    // Start the connection
                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () { vm.init(); });

                    ko.bindingHandlers.masked = {
                        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                            var mask = allBindingsAccessor().mask || {};
                            $(element).mask(mask);
                            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'focusout', function () {
                                var observable = valueAccessor();
                                observable($(element).val());
                            });
                        },
                        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                            $(element).val(value);
                        }
                    };







                });



            </script>
    <!-- ReSharper restore StatementIsNotTerminated -->

            <h2> Add period</h2>
            <form data-bind="submit: addPeriod">
               <input type="date" class="ui-corner-all" data-bind="value: newPeriodFrom" />
               <input type="date" class="ui-corner-all" data-bind="value: newPeriodTo" />
                <input type ="number" class="ui-corner-all" data-bind="value: newPeriodNumber, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" placeholder="Number of period transactions?" />
               <input class="ui-button" type="submit" value="Add" />
            </form>

            <h2>Our periods</h2>


           <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'periodTemplate', foreach: periods }, visible: periods().length > 0">
            </ul>

            <script type="text/html" id="periodTemplate">
                <!--Data Template-->
                <li>

                   <span data-bind="text: validFrom"></span>
                   <span data-bind="text: validTo"></span>
                   <span data-bind="text: number"></span>>
                    <input class="ui-button" type="button" href="#" data-bind="click: remove" value="x"/>

                </li>
            </script>
            <div id="error" class="validation-summary-errors"></div>

        </body>

    </html>
```

and my hub

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
    using ProactisSupportPortal;



    namespace Core
    {
        [HubName("periodTransactionComs")]
        public class PeriodTransactionHub : Hub
        {
            public bool Add(LicencePeriodTransaction licencePeriodTransaction, string sessionId)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var databaseContext = new LGenEntities())
                    {

                        //find the licence where 2session/licence guid 
                        Licence oLicence = databaseContext.Licences.FirstOrDefault(l=>l.session == sessionId); //;

                        if (oLicence != null)
                        {



                            //now add the new licence period transaction

                            var lpt = new LicencePeriodTransaction
                                {
                                    Number = licencePeriodTransaction.Number,
                                    ValidFrom = licencePeriodTransaction.ValidFrom,
                                    ValidTo = licencePeriodTransaction.ValidTo,
                                    LicenceID = oLicence.LicenceId,
                                    Licence = oLicence
                                };

                            databaseContext.LicencePeriodTransactions.Add(lpt);
                           databaseContext.Entry(oLicence).State = EntityState.Unchanged;


                            //commit
                            databaseContext.SaveChanges();
                            //notify connected client
                            Clients.Caller.periodAdded(lpt);

                            return true;
                        }
                        return
                            Clients.Caller.reportError(
                                "Null reference in:  public bool AddPeriodTransaction(LicencePeriodTransaction licencePeriodTransaction, string sessionId) ");


                    }
                }
                catch
                    (Exception ex)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.reportError(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //update
            public bool Update(LicencePeriodTransaction updatedPeriod)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var databaseContext = new LGenEntities())
                    {
                        var oldTask =
                            databaseContext.LicencePeriodTransactions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == updatedPeriod.Id);
                        if (oldTask != null)
                        {
                            oldTask.Number = updatedPeriod.Number;
                            oldTask.ValidTo = updatedPeriod.ValidTo;
                            oldTask.ValidFrom = updatedPeriod.ValidFrom;
                            databaseContext.SaveChanges();
                            Clients.Caller.periodUpdated(oldTask);
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.reportError(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //Remove
            public bool Remove(int licencePeriodTransactionId)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var databaseContext = new LGenEntities())
                    {
                        var licencePeriod =
                            databaseContext.LicencePeriodTransactions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == licencePeriodTransactionId);
                        databaseContext.LicencePeriodTransactions.Remove(licencePeriod);
                        databaseContext.SaveChanges();
                        Clients.Caller.periodRemoved(licencePeriodTransactionId);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.reportError(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            //get all for licence by session.
            public void GetAll(string sessionId)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var databaseContext = new LGenEntities())
                    {

                        var res = databaseContext.LicencePeriodTransactions.Where(p => p.Licence.session == sessionId).ToArray();
                        Clients.Caller.periodAll(res);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Clients.Caller.reportError(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format your date to preferred format on client side or server side:

1. Server side, just make a property to be string and then call ToString on your date with desired format.
2. Client side, you may have computed property that will format date and data bind to that property.

Sample:

```
model.formatedDate = ko.computed(function() {
    return formatDateFunction(model.startDate);
});
```

Check samples http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format for date formatting logic in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom binding in knockout to format your date strings and date values as they enter and leave your view models.

I like to use jQuery and the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library when dealing with dates in javascript, so my custom binding for displaying dates as strings looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateString = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
      var value = valueAccessor(),
        allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
      var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
      if (valueUnwrapped) {
        var pattern = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
        $(element).text(moment(valueUnwrapped).format(pattern));
      }
    }
  }
```

and is applied like this:

```
<span data-bind="dateString: dateData"></span>
```

For handling values, I use a dateValue custom binding that looks like this:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.dateValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
      $(element).change(function () {
        var value = $(element).val();
        if (moment(value).isValid()) {
          valueAccessor()(moment(value).toDate());
        }
      });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
      var value = valueAccessor(),
        allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
      var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
      if (valueUnwrapped) {
        var pattern = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
        $(element).val(moment(valueUnwrapped).format(pattern));
      }
    }
  }
```

and applied like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="dateValue: dateData" />
```

Comment: As soon as I use this code, the values are not returned, and nulls are passed to the hub for both from and too date?

Comment: Joshua, do you see any errors in the console?  Have you included moment.js?  Are the custom bindings above declared before ko.applyBindings is called?  If all of those things are ok, try simplifying your code and posting it in a jsFiddle.  I'd be happy to help you out.